# Sum of numbers occurring in the multiplication table of 8. What's wrong with my code? Desirable output is 440, and I'm getting 33204

Tags: c, initialization, declaration, do-while

Sum of numbers occurring in the multiplication table of 8. What's wrong with my code? Desirable output is 440, and I'm getting 33204.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
  int sum, n, p;
  printf ("Sum of numbers occurring in the multiplication table of 8: ");

  do
    {
      p = 8 * n;
      sum += p;
      n++;

    }
  while (n <= 10);

  printf ("%d", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `n`? Remember that uninitialized variables really *are* uninitialized. With indeterminate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using uninitialized variables

```
int sum, n, p;
```

that have indeterminate values.

As a result your program has undefined behavior.

You need to initialize them like

```
int sum = 0, n = 1, p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize n first. Attaching my code for reference here:[Code and ouput attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cODei.png)

Comment: Please post you code and output as (properly formatted) text in the answer itself, not as a link or an image.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the variable as:

```
int sum = 0, n = 1, p;
```

Because you have not initialized the varaible, they are taking garbage value which is bydefault stored to them and that's why they are giving you a this kind of answer.

Now run the below code and you will get 440 as your answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main ()
{
  int sum = 0, n = 1, p;
  printf ("Sum of numbers occurring in the multiplication table of 8: ");

  do
    {
      p = 8 * n;
      sum += p;
      n++;

    }
  while (n <= 10);

  printf ("%d", sum);

  return 0;
}
```